# How is cconv in matlab implemented?

Tags: matlab, fft, convolution

My understanding was, that these three should be the same, however matlab gives completely different results. The first and third one are in sync with what I calculated by hand, the second one is different.

```
x_1 = [1, 2, 0, 5];
x_2 = [1/2, -1/4, 1, 0, 3/4];

y_2_1 = ifft(fft(x_1, 2) .* fft(x_2, 2))
y_2_2 = cconv(x_2, x_1, 2)
y_2_3 = cconv(x_2(1:2), x_1(1:2), 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

[From the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/cconv.html#buznf6z):

> The modulo-2 circular convolution is equivalent to splitting the linear convolution into two-element arrays and summing the arrays.

So it is not the same to do

```
res = cconv(x_2, x_1, 2);
```

as to do

```
res2 = cconv(x_2, x_1);
res2 = res(1:2);
```

The former is equivalent to

```
res = cconv(x_2, x_1);
res = res(1:2) + res(3:4) + res(5:6) + ...;
```

(padding with zeros if `res` is odd in size).

On the other hand,

```
res3 = ifft(fft(x_1, 2) .* fft(x_2, 2));
```

is equivalent to

```
res3 = fft(x_1(1:2)) .* fft(x_2(1:2));
res3 = ifft(res3);
```

and different from either of the two `cconv` results.